# C# Lambda returns some null values

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

```
opencall.Priority = 
averages.Where(x => x.ProblemCode == opencall.ProblemCode)
.SingleOrDefault().Priority;
```

The above lambda statement returns some nulls because ProblemCode isn't always guaranteed to be in the averages list.

How can I rewrite this statement so that if that is the case opencall.Priority is set to "" instead of the application throwing an error?

Comment: It is not lambda that returns null, but Linq expression.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to provide a new default value for your reference type, other than `null`.

```
opencall.Priority = averages.Where(x => x.ProblemCode == opencall.ProblemCode)
                            .Select(x => x.Priority)
                            .DefaultIfEmpty("")
                            .Single();
```

So `Priority` is a `string`? Note that you don't need `SingleOrDefault` anymore since the query can never throw an exception, because it will return your provided fallback value.

Answer (score 3):

Split it up:

```
 var result = averages.Where(x => x.ProblemCode == opencall.ProblemCode).SingleOrDefault()
 opencall.Priority = result != null ? result.Priority : string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the problem code first, then check if it's null.

```
var possiblyNullProblemCode= 
    averages.Where(
        x => x.ProblemCode == opencall.ProblemCode)
        .SingleOrDefault();

openCall.Priority = 
    possiblyNullProblemCode == null ? 
        string.Empty : 
        possiblyNullProblemCode.Priority;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write:

```
opencall.Priority = 
    averages.Where(x => x.ProblemCode == opencall.ProblemCode)
    .Select(x => x.Priority)
    .SingleOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Priority is string, you could try:

```
var average = averages.Where(x => x.ProblemCode == opencall.ProblemCode).SingleOrDefault()
opencall.Priority = average == null ? "" : average.Priority;
```

Comment: There should be a way to make this easier to read using the null coalescing operator.