# returning default value if a property is null

Tags: c#, linq

As you know there's an extension method called [DefaultIfEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360179%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), based on the documentation:

> **DefaultIfEmpty**:
>
> Returns the elements of the specified sequence or the type parameter's
> default value in a singleton collection if the sequence is empty.

So in this case if the sequence is empty, it returns a default value, for example, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733308/c-sharp-lambda-returns-some-null-values/14733387#14733387) answer:

```
opencall.Priority = averages.Where(x => x.ProblemCode == opencall.ProblemCode)
                            .Select(x => x.Priority)
                            .DefaultIfEmpty("")
                            .Single();
```

in this example if the averages is empty, it returns an empty string, But I want to know is there something like an extention method in linq so that if the preperty (x.Priority) is null, returns a default value?

PS: I know we can check that using a `if` statement:

```
opencall.Priority = averages.Where(x => x.ProblemCode == opencall.ProblemCode)
                            .Select(x => x.Priority)
                            .DefaultIfEmpty("")
                            .Single(); 
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(opencall.Priority))
    opencall.Priority = "Default value";
...
```

I'm just curious to know that, Is there any kind of extension method for doing that?

Comment: Well you can use the null-coalescing operator: `x => x.Priority ?? ""`

Comment: As I mentioned I just wanted to that, How can we do that using extension method like DefaultIfEmpty. By the way Thank you so much :)

Comment: DefaultIfEmpty is about the sequence being empty, not providing a default value per element. Why would you want an extension method when there's already a C# operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same `DefaultOrEmpty` method overload to provide the default value. In the above query since we are trying to fetch the `Priority` property which is of `String` type. You can provide a default value of String in the method overload:-

```
opencall.Priority = averages.Where(x => x.ProblemCode == opencall.ProblemCode)
                            .Select(x => x.Priority)
                            .DefaultIfEmpty("High")
                            .Single();
```

This will result in `High` for non matching rows.